# pass ID when button is clicked to Action link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to assign a certain value for an ID when button/url is clicked.
So that I can display a dynamic list based on this id by passing the id to action link.

Sample of my code (button)

```
<a class="" href="/LaborerSearchByName/Index">
    <img src="/Content/images/b7.png" id="b7"
         onclick="bb7();"
         onmouseover="bigImg(this)"
         onmouseout="normalImg(this)">
</a>
```

The call for action link

```
@Html.Action("Menu", "MenuItem", new { id = "MenuId"})
```

`"MenuId"` must by a dynamic value based on which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes my solution, use Html.ActionLink() -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Menu Text", "Menu" ,"MenuItem", new { id = "MenuId" }, new { @id = "MenuId" })
```

Then say you have image control like this -

```
<img src="/Content/images/b7.png" id="b7"/>
```

Then you have simple JQuery script to replace query string in this way -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#b7").click(function () {
            $("#MenuId").attr("href","/MenuItem/Menu/" + this.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the above script, when you click on the image element, its id (b7) will be used to formulate the anchor tag url. so now when image was clicked, a new url will be assigned to anchor tag on the client side using JQuery. So the final url should be something like this -

```
/MenuItem/Menu/b7
```

**UPDATE:** As per your comment, I am presenting a simple demonstration on how to use JQUERY AJAX to make a GET request with a parameter and get results back on to the UI.

Lets say you have a controller which returns Json -

```
    public JsonResult GetJson(string MenuId)
    {
        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        urls.Add("https://google.com");
        urls.Add("https://bing.com");
        return Json(urls, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then you can call this controller action in a button click using JQuery Ajax in the following way. *In your implementation you should get that dynamic value instead of input text control. For demo purpose I used Input text to get a value and pass it to controller action.*

```
<input type="text" id="Menu" />
<a href="#" id="ClickMe">Click me</a>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function () {

            var o = new Object();
            o.MenuId = $("#Menu").val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetJson")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(o),
                success: function (data) {ou parse data 
                    // This is how we parse returned json string
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        alert(data[i]);
                    });
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When you run the code, you should see following view -

[image]

When you enter the value and click on anchor tag -

[image]

And as a result, you will get all the results parsed -

[image]

Comment: but i can't use ActionLink helper, i only use it so i can display a dynamic menu list based on an id i send, AND I want to use the id to pass >> public ActionResult Menu(int id=0)

Comment: @HanoufD., I am not sure why you cant use ActionLink helper. That is the easiest way, and I gave you a working solution.

Comment: The thing is in actionLink helper i must specify the "text", while I have to call the action Menu(int id=0) and pass it the ID, so it can display my dynamic list of links BASED ON The ID that goes with the actionHelper. Thank you.

Comment: @HanoufD., In that case you dont need Html.Action() at all, all you need to do is on Image Anchor click, you need to make a JQuery AJAX GET call to you server controller action and get results. Then use those results in JQuery and display them as links. Let me know if that can fit your requirement, I can give you a simple prototype.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am reading about this right now, and i think it can solve my question. I will be more thankful, if you could demonstrate your point with example. Thanks again.

Comment: @HanoufD., Please check my updated answer. If that helps you in resolving your issue, then please mark it as answer. And if possible a up vote. Also let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Can I use it in case i must return a partial View in My public ActionResult Menu(string MenuId = "0"){} ?

Comment: @HanoufD., yes you can use it to return partial view. But in JQuery you will be getting html instead of json. So you need to use html and populate that html string to some div or any other placeholder appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Rami. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @HanoufD. Not a problem at all. Any time for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` using your function `onclick="bb7(this);"`
then in JavaScript part use `setAttribute` in you function: `bb2(this){this.setAttribute("id","someID");}`